# bootstrap and rails 4.0 .make-grid-columns is undefined

Tags: ruby-on-rails, less, twitter-bootstrap-3

I had this project on `RubyOnRails 4.0` with gems `less (2.3.2)` and `less-rails (2.3.2)`. And basically I download twitter-bootstrap less sources and put it into `app/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap`.

Then I call bootstrap in my `.less` file (Located at `/app/assets/stylesheets/style.css.less`) like this

```
// Place all the styles related to the style controller here.
// They will automatically be included in application.css.
// You can use Less here: http://lesscss.org/

@import "bootstrap/bootstrap.less";

// Nothing more
```

Also include the file in my `aplication.css` like this

```
/*
 * This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.css, which will include all the files
 * listed below.
 *
 * Any CSS and SCSS file within this directory, lib/assets/stylesheets, vendor/assets/stylesheets,
 * or vendor/assets/stylesheets of plugins, if any, can be referenced here using a relative path.
 *
 * You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at the top of the
 * compiled file, but it's generally better to create a new file per style scope.
 *
 *= require_self
 *= require style.css.less
 */
```

But when I start my server it shows this error `.make-grid-columns is undefined`

[image]

The weird is that, if i compile the file with my `npm less` compiler, it gives no error and compiles great. `Any ideas?` I dont want the twitter-bootstrap gem couse that is not the way my company works, we use the bootstrap sources.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is probably related with less version as the latest bootstrap require at least less 2.5. The latest less-rails is tied to less ~> 2.4.0, moving that to less ~> 2.5 should help.

Solution for that [issue](https://github.com/metaskills/less-rails/pull/84) is waiting for merging in less-rails project until it will happen you could use that branch:

```
gem "less-rails", git: "git@github.com:CQQL/less-rails.git", branch: "less-2.5"
```

Comment: The latest version of Less is [1.7.0 according to their GitHub repo](https://github.com/less/less.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md).

Did you mean 1.5?

Comment: less-rails is tied to gem called [less] (http://rubygems.org/gems/less) (gem.add_runtime_dependency 'less', '~> 2.5.0') not less.js, the version is correct.

Answer (score 0):

gem 'less-rails',  :git =>  'git@github.com:metaskills/less-rails.git'